# safari cookies only persist after disabling prevent cross site tracking in settings please answer

Tags: node.js, reactjs, cookies, browser, safari

After authorization, cookies with tokens should be saved on the client, but they are saved only if you disable prevent cross site tracking in the safari settings, but even then for some reason they are still not visible in the cookies tab, but on the site you can see that you are authorized. This is how I set cookies on the server:
`response.cookie("access", accessToken, {httpOnly: true, sameSite: 'none', secure:true});`
I probably think it might be because of sameSite: none, but if sameSite is not specified as none, then cookies are not saved at all in any browser.
What to do?
Client and api hosted on heroku.
[client].herokuapp.com [server].herokuapp.com
Please answer!